# Home page with jquery scale animation not loading up at the first time

Tags: jquery, wordpress, scale

I have this problem:
On my home page of a developing Wordpress site: http://baksagaspar.com/MH-work/  I have an animation with this jQuery + jQueryUI(scale) script:

```
jQuery(function($) {  

// home image set dimensions related to screen size
var Swidth = screen.width;
var imgw = $('#main-back-imghome').width();
var imgh = $('#main-back-imghome').height();
var imgpercent = (imgw / Swidth);
var imgWN = imgw * imgpercent;
var imgHN = imgh * imgpercent;

// now show  
$('#main-back-imghome').css( {width: imgWN, height: imgHN} ).center().hide().delay(1000).show("scale", {}, 3500);

  });
```

The problem I have is that when I first visit the page, the animation is not triggering, but on refresh, and after that everything is fine. it is really distracting for the first time visitors to get a complete blank page on first-enter :-(

My idea was to somehow test if the animation has triggered, and if not - to start it, but maybe that's not the right way...

Any suggestions how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the animation is triggered but it doesn't know how big the half megabyte image is when it starts. Everything works fine on refresh because the image is in the browser's cache by that time.

In your HTML, you have this:

```
<img id="main-back-imghome" src=".." />
```

Notice that you don't have `width` or `height` attributes. When you do this on the first load:

```
var imgw = $('#main-back-imghome').width();
var imgh = $('#main-back-imghome').height();
```

The image data won't be loaded so the width and height will be zero and so `imgWN` and `imgHN` will also be zero.

I'd put `width` and `height` attributes on `#main-back-imghome` and `style="display:none;"`; then, change the initial `.css()` call to this:

```
$('#main-back-imghome').css({
    width: imgWN,
    height: imgHN,
    display: 'inline-block'
})
```

The `width` and `height` attributes should give you useful `imgWN` and `imgHN` values even when the image data hasn't loaded. Starting with `display:none` should avoid an initial shrink from full size to your scaled down starting size; you can also try starting with `visibility:hidden` and `visibility: 'visible'` in the `.css()` call if messing with `display` doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, it seems it solved the issue. 
The only thing what is left is that on first time the image gets a bit too big when showed, but anyway it is much better than seeing nothing.
Thank you for the help!